# Почему нельзя сделать свой оператор С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Почему нельзя перегрузить свой оператор? Это же удобно.

Comment: А приоритеты? А ассоциативность? Это все надо как-то пояснять компилятору. Да и синтаксический анализ при этом тоже, мягко говоря, не упрощается... А удобства - ну как бы это сказать... они достаточно сомнительны даже от перегрузки доступных операторов.

Comment: спасибо! и правда это так. Хотите, перепешите как ответ, отблагодарю=)

Comment: а собственно то и возможных символов для "своих операторов" почти что и нет.  Наверно только $ и @. А все остальное занято.

Comment: например, еще `**`

Comment: И как при этом пояснить, что это, например, возведение в степень, а не умножение на разыменованное значение? :) Нет, в принципе, решаемо, конечно, все, вопрос только - стоит ли оно того.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании своих операторов встает масса вопросов - в частности, об их приоритетах, ассоциативности и тому подобном. Все это следует каким-то образом пояснять компилятору. Кроме того, возникает ряд проблем с синтаксическим анализом исходного кода.

При этом многие авторы умных книг, мягко говоря, не в восторге от возможности переопределения даже имеющихся операторов. Особенно если их семантика оказывается далекой от семантики стандартных операторов.

Такие удачные перегрузки, как `>>` и `<<` - скорее исключения, подтверждающие правило..

Comment: Хотя в целом согласен со сказанным, для справки хочу добавить, что есть, как минимум, один язык, где это реализовано, работает и активно применяется - Haskell

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Я не написал, что это *невозможно*. Возможно, но просто эта овчинка не стоит выделки...

Comment: я этого и не говорил... Всего лишь дал информацию для справки ТС, вдруг ему будет интересно. К Вашему ответу у меня претензий нет. Павда - стоит ли овчинка выделки, я судить не возьмусь.